# Salesforce External Service - Capturing Request and Response

Tags: apex, callout, external-services

We are doing POC to use [external services](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/external-services/use-external-services-in-a-flow) for integrating with external systems.

It works well.With spring 20 as per preview release notes enhanced external service is going GA.

**Question:**

> Is there a way we can log the request and response that goes out
>   through the apex actions generated by external services?

Previously when we used to make callouts using apex code, we used to log request and response in a custom object but with external services its taken out of our hands.

Any ideas/suggestions on how to implement it?

Comment: When you register the external services, doesn't Salesforce generate some proxy Apex classes to the actions? If so, you could modify those as required. Failing that, I'd check the debug logs for the callouts.

Comment: @DanielBallinger, unfortunately we cannot edit the code generated by external services apex classes.

Comment: @RedDevil Did you find a way to solve this?